# Regex cant limit search range

Tags: php, regex

I have following problem:

I have a pattern like this:

```
/(?<=template=")(.*?)(.*\/)/gm
```

And an text like this:

```
template="test/widgets/glasgow.phtml"}}
```

My regex should search for the path infront of my file, i need to cut it out so that it will look at the end like this:

```
   template="glasgow.phtml"}}
```

That works fine but the problem is that i have sometimes an text that looks like this:

```
block="core/template" template="test/widgets/getcallus.phtml"}}</p>
```

It cuts everything out till the `</`.

This is getting cutted out:

```
test/widgets/getcallus.phtml"}}</
```

Instead of:

```
test/widgets/
```

I have tried to limit the end with `$` but it doesnt do nothing.

I am testing it on regexr.com

https://regexr.com/50hi2

Comment: Try `template="\K[^"\/]*\/[^"\/]*\/`, see https://regex101.com/r/dev3o2/1

Comment: Thank you thats helping me to continue my work

Comment: in 5 min you get your solution as "accepted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
template="\K[^"\/]*\/[^"\/]*\/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dev3o2/1). In PHP, you may get rid of backslashes if you specify another regex delimiter:

```
$regex = '~template="\K[^"/]*/[^"/]*/~';
```

**Details**

- `template="` - literal text
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[^"\/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/` and `"`
- `\/` -  a `/` char
- `[^"\/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/` and `"`
- `\/` -  a `/` char

It is equal to `template="\K(?:[^"\/]*\/){2}`, where `(?:...){2}` repeats the non-capturing group sequence of patterns twice.

Comment: works well but could you checkout why the last string in the element doenst match? https://regex101.com/r/dev3o2/3

Comment: @Ifaruki Make last `/` optional, add a `?` after it, `template="\K[^"\/]*\/[^"\/]*\/?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dev3o2/4).

Comment: the problem here is it marked the file name too `glasgow.phtml` in this case, it shouldnt

Comment: @Ifaruki Try `template="\K[^"\/]+\/(?:[^"\/.]+\/)?` where the second part requires a `/` at the end, and does not allow `.` inside, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dev3o2/5). You should provide exact rules for this, otherwise, "it-matches-here-and-not-here" game may be endless.

Comment: Thank you thats the solution! I will now try to understand that regex on my own thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `(.*?)(.*\/)`

This pattern corresponds to a REDOS vulnerability. (There are 2^n ways to read the n chars before the last `/`...

To keep a regex closed to yours, you can use 
`/(?<=template=")([^"]*?\/)*([^"]*)"/`

`([^"]*?\/)*` reads as many blocks "non `/` nor `"` chars followed by `/`" as possible.

https://regex101.com/r/SMSv5R/2